Square API integration
I'm trying to build a Square app that, when installed by the Square user, reads out available store data to another platform. This other platform will use the store data to make recommendations, etc.
I have never used Square's API before and I am running in circles trying to get something basic running in the sandbox on localhost.
Most recently, I keep getting this error in the console:
GET https://squareupsandbox.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=sandbox-XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX&scope=MERCHANT_PROFILE_READ&state=9a0ahl&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapi%2Fsquare%2Fcallback 400 (Bad Request)

This is my .env
NEXT_PUBLIC_SQUARE_APPLICATION_ID=sandbox-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX
SQUARE_ACCESS_TOKEN=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
SQUARE_REDIRECT_URL=http://localhost:3000/api/square/callback

Here is /lib/squareClient.js:
const { Client } = require('square');

const squareClient = new Client({
  environment: 'sandbox', // or 'production' for live apps
  accessToken: process.env.SQUARE_ACCESS_TOKEN,
});

module.exports = squareClient;

here is /api/square.js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
const squareClient = require('../lib/squareClient');

export default async function handler(req = NextApiRequest, res = NextApiResponse) {
  const { method } = req;

  switch (method) {
    case 'GET':
      // Example: Fetch merchant data
      try {
        const merchantsApi = squareClient.merchantsApi;
        const response = await merchantsApi.listMerchants();
        res.status(200).json(response.result);
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
      }
      break;

    default:
      res.setHeader('Allow', ['GET']);
      res.status(405).end(`Method ${method} Not Allowed`);
  }
}

here is /pages/api/square/callback.js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export default async function handler(req = NextApiRequest, res = NextApiResponse) {
  // Log all query parameters for debugging
  console.log('Callback received with query params:', req.query);

  const { code, state, error } = req.query;

  if (error) {
    console.error('Square OAuth error:', error);
    return res.redirect(`/?error=${encodeURIComponent(error)}`);
  }

  if (!code) {
    return res.redirect('/?error=No authorization code received');
  }

  try {
    // Log success and redirect
    console.log('Successfully received authorization code');
    res.redirect('/?success=true');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Callback error:', err);
    res.redirect(`/?error=${encodeURIComponent(err.message)}`);
  }
}

and here is /pages/index.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';

export default function Home() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const connectSquare = () => {
    try {
      const state = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
      
      // Build OAuth URL with minimal required parameters
      const authParams = new URLSearchParams({
        'client_id': process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SQUARE_APPLICATION_ID,
        'scope': 'MERCHANT_PROFILE_READ',
        'state': state,
        'response_type': 'code',
        'redirect_uri': `${window.location.origin}/api/square/callback`
      });

      const authUrl = `https://squareupsandbox.com/oauth2/authorize?${authParams.toString()}`;
      
      // Log the URL for debugging
      console.log('Redirecting to:', authUrl);
      
      // Redirect to Square's OAuth page
      window.location.href = authUrl;
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message);
      console.error('Error during Square connection:', err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Square Integration App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Connect your Square account" />
      </Head>

      <main style={{ padding: '20px', maxWidth: '800px', margin: '0 auto' }}>
        <h1 style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}>Square Integration App</h1>
        
        {error && (
          <div style={{ 
            padding: '10px', 
            marginBottom: '20px', 
            backgroundColor: '#fee', 
            border: '1px solid #f00',
            borderRadius: '4px'
          }}>
            Error: {error}
          </div>
        )}

        <div style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}>
          <p>Click the button below to connect your Square account.</p>
          <p style={{ fontSize: '14px', color: '#666' }}>
            This will redirect you to Square's secure login page.
          </p>
        </div>

        <button 
          onClick={connectSquare}
          style={{
            padding: '10px 20px',
            fontSize: '16px',
            backgroundColor: '#006aff',
            color: 'white',
            border: 'none',
            borderRadius: '4px',
            cursor: 'pointer'
          }}
        >
          Connect Your Square Account
        </button>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

When I click the "Connect Your Square Account" button, I get the error at the top of the post.
Not sure where I'm going wrong.
